# Sample app runs fine with library as a module, but not as an external dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I have a library which itself has a few dependencies, namely Realm, Retrofit, as well as a native library. The native library is on github and I can successfully pull it into my project via jitpack.

I have a sample app which im using to test this library. In my sample apps 'app' module `build.gradle` i my dependencies block looks somewhat like the following:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':sdk')
    ...
    //compile realm,rx,retrofit, etc..
}
```

When doing this, my sample app works correctly.

Now lets say I either:

- Grab the sdk's generated .jar file and put it in my sample apps /libs
- Get the .aar and do the same as above
- Put the repo on jitpack and try to download it via compile 'xxxx'

Trying to include the sdk in my sample app any of these other ways does not seem to work and spits out unhelpful errors.

What could possibly be the issue? I got a hint that it may be an issue with 'transitive dependencies' but am not sure where to start.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your Github project if it's a public one?

Comment: Sure, the native lib being used inside my library is http://github.com/rockmyworld/basslib-android but the actual library is private (unfortunately). Though any specific data you need Ill try to provide.